# Asked or Bid price which one is right

Tags: bid-ask

I recently bought shares on a market where I normally buy and we're confirmed at asked price sorry not bid please see attached pictures and number of shares were confirmed and a congratulations note sent as normal but at open time price was changed but I screenshot my buying price each time.

Can they do that
Ask one price and confirm number of shares when you buy but later changed it?

What is want to know is that legal?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The picture is missing.

Comment: But I loaded it. Please advise because it doesn't allow to add on this message but I have to load new one again. Is the answer email address where I can send it?

Comment: Am trying to load it says I need 10 reputations to load a picture.  How can I send this proof for clarity then.?

Comment: What are reputations in this context?  I need to load picture as proof needed to clarify my question but this system says I need 10 reputations to load a picture

Comment: Eg Bid price 300 / Asked Price 50 / last price 300 So when I place my order on the platform shares were sold at middle price (Asked price) and confirmed but at open time the following day 300 was charged for shares not what was asked the one in the middle though congratulations were sent as usual they do when I buy one the platform. Hope this is clear I am unable to attach screenshot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Seller Sells Stock At Bid But Charged At Asked?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/139548/why-seller-sells-stock-at-bid-but-charged-at-asked)

Comment: No in my case stock was sold at asked but later changed to bid. This is my confusion

Comment: Where is the picture?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiBsa.png

Comment: Here is the picture above.  Can someone help me them. I bought at middle price and shares for that price were allocated each for asked price bit after makes was opened they changed to bid price.

Comment: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBF3T.png)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWCQI.png

Comment: Hope all these 3 pictures  above help to answer my question.

Comment: @JOYMATSOSO Please edit your question, and add those pictures to the question body. Thank you.